# Should an extracted audio sample be contained inside its original source when comparing bytes?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Let's say that I have an audio wav file with the sentence:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| meta data | 'Audio recognition sometimes is trick' |.wav
+-----------+----------------------------------------+
```

Now consider opening this audio in Audacity and extracting and saving the word 'sometimes' in another file based on its wave draw.

```
+-----------+-------------+
| meta data | 'sometimes' |.wav
+-----------+-------------+
```

Then I used this Java code to get the audio data only from both files:

```
    //...
    Path source = Paths.get("source.wav");
    Path sample = Paths.get("sometimes.wav");
    int index = compare(transform(source), transform(sample));
    System.out.println("Shouldn't I be greater than -1!? " + (index > -1));
    //...

    private int compare(int[] source, int[] sample) throws IOException {
        return Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(source), Arrays.asList(sample));
    }

    private int[] transform(Path audio) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    try (AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(audio)))) {

        AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
        byte[] audioBytes = new byte[(int) (ais.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize())];
        int nlengthInSamples = audioBytes.length / 2;
        int[] audioData = new int[nlengthInSamples];
        for (int i = 0; i < nlengthInSamples; i++) {
            int LSB = audioBytes[2*i]; /* First byte is LSB (low order) */
            int MSB = audioBytes[2*i+1]; /* Second byte is MSB (high order) */
            audioData[i] = (MSB << 8) | (255 & LSB);
        }
        return audioData;
    }
}
```

Now comes my question again.

***Shouldn't this code be able to find 'sometimes' audio data bytes inside the original audio file considering the extraction mentioned before?***

I tried comparing contents as String but no lucky at all:

```
new String(source).contains(new String(sample));
```

Can someone point what I missing here?

Comment: Are these uncompressed (PCM) WAVs? Also, what's the frame size in your two files?

Comment: I am confused by the method to read the audio files. Why not use "AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);" This assumes that you pass the URL for the file instead of a Path, which should work whether or not the resource is within the jar or external to the program. Then, test comparing the byte[] arrays before testing after decoding to PCM. That is my suggestion, what I would do as a first step to solving the question. If the original file and the Audacity clip are not the same format, the resulting PCM would surely also be dissimilar, even if sounds same.

Comment: @Phil. Actually your first suggestion simplifies some lines, thanks. But even comparing the bytes with no conversion I am not able do find the sample inside the source audio file. Considering I have extracted the sample from source using Audacity it's supposed to be kept the number of channels, rate, and so on, right? Even so, here  is what AudioFormat obtained from AudioInputStream shows: PCM_SIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
PCM_SIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian

Comment: @NPE PCM_SIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian for both files.

Comment: Yes, hence "first step." Keep hacking away the "impossible" and review the "highly improbable" that is left over. On the face of it, it seems one should be able to find the sample. Here is another idea: search for a fragment extracted from within the Audacity clip, something pretty small, like maybe just a dozen bytes. If the Audacity program is making changes to the file in the process of making the clip, the greatest likelihood is that it will be near the start or end, not middle. Also, verify the compare works by extracting a small bit from the source file and compare that to the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Phil, you are the guy! Your tips led me to the solution!

1. Audacity sample audio extraction was encoding the sample bytes in some different way;
2. I wrote a Java program to identify silence in the source audio and then I splitted some 
   samples word by word;
3. Comparing the source and the new non-audacity samples matched!

Here are the the new transform and compare:

```
private int compare(byte[] captchaData, byte[] sampleData) throws IOException {
    return new String(captchaData).indexOf(new String(sampleData));
}

private byte[] transform(Path audio) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audio.toFile());
    AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        int nBufferSize = 1024 * format.getFrameSize();
        byte[] abBuffer = new byte[nBufferSize];
        int nBytesRead;
        while ((nBytesRead = ais.read(abBuffer)) > -1) {
            baos.write(abBuffer, 0, nBytesRead);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

The splitter:

```
private List<byte[]> split(byte[] audioData) {
    System.out.println(audioData.length);
    List<byte[]> byteList = new ArrayList<>();
    int zeroCounter = 0;
    int lastPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < audioData.length; i++) {
        if (audioData[i] >= -1 && audioData[i] <= 1) {
            zeroCounter++; //too many leading 'zeros' could indicate silence or very low noise...
        } else if (zeroCounter > 0) {
            if (zeroCounter > 2000) {
                int from = lastPos;
                int to = i - (zeroCounter/2);
                byteList.add(
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(
                        audioData,
                        from,
                        to));
                System.out.println("split from: " + from + " to: " + to);
                lastPos = to;
            }
            zeroCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    return byteList;
}
```

Thanks!